# Windows 7 install on MacBook Air without Bootcamp

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I burned  my DVD of Windows 7 64 bit to an iso file. Moved that file to my USB flash drive using Rufus, and when I boot while holding the option key my flash drive isn't recognized. Not sure what else to do but Bootcamp only supports Windows 8 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your MacBook Air is 2015 or newer model. If so, then you can not install Windows 7 on this model. The reason is that Windows 7 requires a BIOS boot method and Apple removed the ability to BIOS boot operating systems starting with the 2015 model year Macs.

The instructions for installing Windows 8.1 are given at the Apple web site: [Use Windows 8.1 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457).

The instructions for installing Windows 10 are given at the Apple web site: [Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990).

Comment: Thanks David. So I must use Windows 8 or 10?

Comment: @timmyspan: I updated my answer to include instructions for Windows 8.1 and 10.